# Why is it so common to multiply matrices and vectors like $x^T Q x$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, vectors, symmetric-matrices

Matrices and their operations were always a bit unintuitive to me, and I was wondering why they appear in this formation so often:

$x^T Q x$

where $x$ is a $n$ length vector and $Q$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix. Is there a reason why this formation is so common (aside from keeping dimensions consistent with matrix multiplication rules)? I've always thought of this as a way to sort of multiply a matrix by the square of a vector, but I've put this hypothesis together only due to there being two $x$'s and one $Q$.

If it is relevant, I am encountering this formation very often while learning about optimization.

Comment: If $Q$ is positive definite, so that $Q = A^TA$, then $x^TQx = x^TA^TAx = (Ax)^T (Ax) = (Ax, Ax)$ in the usual inner product.  So, what we have is an inner product after a change of basis.  So if inner products are important, and change of bases are important, then you would expect such expressions (aka [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form#Definitions)) to be important as well.

Comment: If $x$ is a vector of unknowns, it's also a compact way to write a 2nd-degree homogeneous polynomial. For instance, if $x=[x_1 \, x_2]^T$ and $Q=\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix} q_{1,1} & q_{1,2} \\ q_{1,2} & q_{2,2} \end{smallmatrix}\bigr]$ (a symmetric matrix), then $x^T Q x = q_{1,1} x_1^2 + 2 q_{1,2}x_1 x_2 + q_{2,2} x_2^2$.

Comment: This is just a compact way to write a general quadratic form $\sum_{i,j}Q_{i,j}x_ix_j$. Additionally it has the nice property that the quadratic form is convex iff Q is PSD, which is crucial for convex quadratic optimization.

Comment: With the trace operator you can bring this term even closer to "multiply a matrix by the square of a vector", as then $x^TQx=trace(Qxx^T)$.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the expression $x^TQx$ occurs so frequently in a variety of fields including optimization is very likely due to its close connection to the Taylor expansion of a real function of $n$ variables.

Let us reestablish this connection. Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed point, let $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a fixed direction and let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$ \phi(t) = x + th.$$
Then the function $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$g = f \circ \phi$$
is differentiable by the chain rule and
$$ g'(t) = Df(\phi(t))\phi'(t)$$
where $Df(y)$ is the gradient of $f$ at the point $y$, i.e., the row vector
$$ Df(y) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(y),  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(y), \dotsc,  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(y) \end{pmatrix} $$
In particular, we have
$$g'(0) = Df(x)\phi'(0) = Df(x)h.$$
We shall continue to differentiate. We have
$$g'(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x+th)h_j$$
and by the chain rule we have
$$g''(t) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x+th)h_jh_i.$$
In particular, we have
$$ g''(0) = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x)h_jh_i = h^T Q h$$
where $Q = [q_{ij}] \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the matrix given by
$$ q_{ij} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(x)$$
Now suppose that we seek information about the function $f$ in the vicinity of a point $x$. It is natural that we consider all possible directions $h$ and the associated functions $g$. We have the usual Taylor expansion
$$g(t) = g(0) + g'(0)t + g''(0)t^2 + O(t^3), \quad t \rightarrow 0, \quad t \not =0$$
which in our case translates to
$$g(t) = f(x) + Df(x)th + (th)^T Q (th) + O(t^3), \quad t \rightarrow 0, \quad t \not = 0.$$
In the case of optimization we are probably looking at the stationary points of $f$ characterized by $Df(x) =0$ and at these points the term $h^TQh$ dictates the local behavior of $f$.